# It is good practice to get all object in RetrieveUpdateDestroy Method?

Tags: django, database, generics, django-rest-framework, django-views

Why we need to get all object in RetrieveUpdateDestroy Method?

In real project can I do it just like this Without fear even if there is large data?
[image]

Comment: It will not fetch all items: a `QuerySet` is *lazy*: it will have extra filtering with the primary key, and thus retrieve/delete the single object...

Answer (score 1):

> Why [do] we need to get all object[s] in [a] `RetrieveUpdateDestroy` [view]?

We **don't**: the queryset is *not* evaluated. This is only used as a "parent" queryset to make querysets to retrieve, update, and delete a single object.

Indeed, for a `retrieve` method, it will add `.get(pk=some_pk)` at the end, and thus make a query to retrieve that single object.

The queryset can be used to filter certain items, to prevent retrieving, updating and removing certain objects for example. You can for example use `queryset = Student.objects.filter(active=True)` to only be able to retrieve active `Student`s.